# programmatically implement UIScrollView in a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode4.2, uitextview, uialertview

I would like to programmatically Add a UIScrollView in a UIAlertView.

I found a way to do that but I was not successful in adding text to this UIScrollView (using the same code as in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SG0CAAl5u0).

is there an alternative to do that? the text I have is very long and I need people to be able to scroll but without being able to edit it.

I know that the Apple user interface guideline does not recommend long text in alerts (although detecting WiFi networks does that) but I have no choice but doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a large text in `UIAlertView` it automatically becomes scrollable. 
You don't have to do any thing to make it scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a control on github](https://github.com/digdog/DDAlertPrompt) that has a tabelView inside it. If you need to customize beyond what Inder suggests, you might want to look at the code and replace the tableView with a scrollView.

Also, there are other controls at [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/) that might help you directly or give you some ideas.